# Rendering a partial with ajax - missing view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

I have commendations/_create.html.erb which includes in a form -

```
<%= form_for(current_user.commendations.new(...), remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%=...
```

and in commendations_controller.rb

```
def create
...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

but I'm getting the following error in the server log -

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template commendations/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/dan/Documents/ROR/fic/app/views"
  * "/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"):
  app/controllers/commendations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

I can't see where I'm going wrong - the `remote: true` should trigger `format.js` which in turn should reload the partial, no?

In routes.rb I have

```
 resources :commendations, only: [:create]
```

Comment: 1. where is the `commendations/create` is placed? 2. please issue `touch Users/dan/Documents/ROR/fic/app/views/application/_create.html.erb` and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a file called create.js within app/views/commendations/

And in create.js do:

```
$("#your_div").html( "<%= j render( :partial => 'commendations/your_partial') %>" );
```